# Win 8.1 app - Windows store Reject error - API not supported for this application type

Tags: dll, windows-store-apps, windows

I'm trying to upload my first app the the windows store and get this reject error :

```
API System.IO.FileInfo in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.x86.exe calls this API.
API System.Diagnostics.TraceLevel in SYSTEM, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.x86.exe calls this API.
API System.IO.DirectoryInfo in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.x86.exe calls this API.
API System.IO.FileSystemInfo in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.x86.exe calls this API.
API System.Threading.ThreadStart in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.x86.exe calls this API.
API System.Reflection.MemberTypes in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.x86.exe calls this API.
API System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(System.String) in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.x86.exe calls this API.
API System.Enum.ToObject(System.Type,System.Int32) in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.x86.exe calls this API.
API System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Int32) in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.x86.exe calls this API.
API System.Type.get_Module in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.x86.exe calls this API.
API System.Reflection.Assembly.get_Location in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.x86.exe calls this API.
API System.IO.FileInfo.#ctor(System.String) in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.x86.exe calls this API.
API System.IO.FileInfo.get_Directory in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.x86.exe calls this API.
API System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetFiles in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.x86.exe calls this API.
API System.IO.FileSystemInfo.get_Name in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.x86.exe calls this API.
API System.IO.FileSystemInfo.get_Extension in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.x86.exe calls this API.
API System.Threading.ThreadStart.#ctor(System.Object,System.IntPtr) in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.x86.exe calls this API.
API System.Threading.Thread.#ctor(System.Threading.ThreadStart) in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.x86.exe calls this API.
API System.Threading.Thread.Start in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.x86.exe calls this API.
API System.Reflection.PropertyInfo.op_Inequality(System.Reflection.PropertyInfo,System.Reflection.PropertyInfo) in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.x86.exe calls this API.
API System.Reflection.FieldInfo.op_Inequality(System.Reflection.FieldInfo,System.Reflection.FieldInfo) in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.x86.exe calls this API.
API System.Reflection.MethodInfo.op_Inequality(System.Reflection.MethodInfo,System.Reflection.MethodInfo) in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.x86.exe calls this API.
API System.Type.GetMember(System.String,System.Reflection.MemberTypes,System.Reflection.BindingFlags) in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.x86.exe calls this API.
API System.Type.op_Inequality(System.Type,System.Type) in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.x86.exe calls this API.
API System.Reflection.MethodInfo.op_Equality(System.Reflection.MethodInfo,System.Reflection.MethodInfo) in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.x86.exe calls this API.
API System.Type.op_Equality(System.Type,System.Type) in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.x86.exe calls this API.
API System.Reflection.EventInfo.op_Inequality(System.Reflection.EventInfo,System.Reflection.EventInfo) in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.x86.exe calls this API.
API System.Type.GetInterface(System.String,System.Boolean) in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.x86.exe calls this API.
API System.Reflection.MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributesData in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.x86.exe calls this API.
API System.Reflection.CustomAttributeData.get_Constructor in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.x86.exe calls this API.
API System.Reflection.CustomAttributeNamedArgument.get_MemberInfo in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.x86.exe calls this API.
API System.Type.GetType(System.String,System.Func{System.Reflection.AssemblyName,System.Reflection.Assembly},System.Func{System.Reflection.Assembly,System.String,System.Boolean,System.Type}) in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.x86.exe calls this API.
API System.Type.EmptyTypes in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.x86.exe calls this API.
API System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.op_Inequality(System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo,System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo) in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.x86.exe calls this API.
API System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.op_Equality(System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo,System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo) in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.x86.exe calls this API.
API System.Threading.ApartmentState in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Core.dll calls this API.
```

Does somebody knows what this error mean?

Comment: Has you run and created your package in release mode? Does your package pass the local WACK test without problem? If so, you could create a [support ticket](http://aka.ms/storesupport) through your developer account so that support can review your specific submission.

Comment: Yes, i created it in realse mode and run the local tester and it show me the same error.